# file_get_contents not working on Asterisk Now

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I install Asterisk now 6.12 32 bit, and run code php like this:

```
<?php 
    $link = 'http://www.bongda.com.vn/feed/';
    $content = file_get_contents($link);
    print_r($content);
?>
```

`file_get_contents`  not working :( ,but i can run code php on wamp server in windows 7.

Comment: "__not working__" is half way to get your question closed. Add this at the top of your php script, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` what does it spit ?

Answer (score 0):

- Stream Wrapper for URL could be missing from PHP installation
- allow_url_fopen is disables in /etc/php.ini
- Some kind of firewall settings (iptables) prevent outgoing access

To help debugging, check /var/log/httpd/error_log.
I would presonally suggest using the php cURL library for online sources instead of file_get_content.